# Run Flask without port

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, flask

I have a flask server running on ubuntu. I want to hit the server using my domain name, test.example.com, without having to include the port number. Right now, I can successfully access the server by doing https://test.example.com:80/ but I can't figure out how to do just https://test.example.com/

In flask_server.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=0.0.0.0, port=80, ssl_conext=context)
```

Comment: https port by default is not 80, but 443. So you are forcing flask to listen on 80 , and then it becomes mandatory to use the port in URL. Dont set anything, you will be fine or set as 443.

Comment: flask development server is not a preferred production server. Use a WSGI server like gunicorn / waitress , and use a front-proxy server like nginx to handle SSL

Answer (score 0):

Use a proxy forwading, like a basic NGinx server in front of your flask website
Nginx gonna take the HTTPS/Domain on the 443 port part and forward the query to you local flask server on the localhost:80